# Angular 7: How to build scripts and styles when routing to another applications

Tags: angular, routes, angular7

I have 2 applications: Client, Admin.

The file structure for the application is something like this:

```
├─ projects/
|   ├─ admin/
|   |   ├─ admin.module.ts
|   |   ├─ admin.component.ts
|   |   └─ profile/
|   |      └─ profile.component.ts
|   └─ client/
|      ├─ client.module.ts
|      ├─ client.component.ts
|      ├─ home/
|      |   └─ home.component.ts
|      └─ login/
|          └─ login.component.ts
└─ src/
    └─ app/
       ├─ app.module.ts
       ├─ app.component.ts
       └─ app.routing.ts
```

Here is my `angular.json`:

```
{
"projects": {
    "default": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "options": {
            "styles": [],
            "scripts": []
          }
      },
    "admin": {
      "root": "projects/admin/",
      "sourceRoot": "projects/admin/src",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "options": {
            "styles": [
              "projects/admin/src/assets/styles.css",
              "projects/admin/src/assets/bootstrap.min.css",
              "projects/admin/src/assets/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css",
              "projects/admin/src/assets/buttons.bootstrap.min.css",
              "projects/admin/src/assets/custom.min.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "projects/admin/src/assets/bootstrap.min.js",
              "projects/admin/src/assets/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js",
              "projects/admin/src/assets/buttons.bootstrap.min.js",
              "projects/admin/src/assets/custom.min.js"
            ]
          }
      },
    "client": {
      "root": "projects/client/",
      "sourceRoot": "projects/client/src",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "options": {
            "styles": [
              "projects/client/src/assets/styles.css",
              "projects/client/src/assets/core.min.css",
              "projects/client/src/assets/custom.min.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "projects/client/src/assets/core.min.js",
              "projects/client/src/assets/custom.min.js"
            ]
          }
      }
    }
"defaultProject": "default"
}
```

Here is my `AdminModule (admin.module.ts)` :

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'admin',
    component: AdminLayoutComponent,
    children: [
      { path: 'profile', component: AdminProfileComponent }
    ]
  }
];
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AdminModule { }
```

Here is my `ClientModule (client.module.ts)` :

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },

  {
    path: '',
    component: ClientLayoutComponent,
    children: [
      { path: '', component: ClientHomeComponent, pathMatch: 'full' }
    ]
  },

  // otherwise redirect to home
  { path: '**', redirectTo: '' }
];
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class ClientModule { }
```

Here is my `AppModule (app.module.ts)` :

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule.withServerTransition({ appId: 'ng-cli-universal' }),
    HttpClientModule,
    FormsModule,
    AdminModule,
    ClientModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

The problem is when routing to any component of another applications (Admin/Client), I want to build all scripts and styles are declared in `angular.json`, but it doesn't.
Do you have any solutions to solve this problem?

Sorry for my bad English. Hope you understand.
Thank you very much.

Comment: ` I want to build all scripts and styles are declared in angular.json` , why are you creating separate projects ? any special reason  ?

Comment: Because these projects have difference script and style files. As far as you see, Admin project needs a lot of script and style files, but Client project just needs the "core" file.

Comment: you mean to build them both in one command? `npm run bulid admin && npm run build client` ??? You can add this command to your package.json scripts section. Also with production switches: `npm run bulid admin --prod && npm run build client --prod`

Comment: @JohnnyDevNull yes, I want to build them both. But Client and Admin have different script/style files. How can I just use scripts/styles in every specific application, because they have a lot of scripts/styles?

Comment: Maybe you could use two separate application rather than two separate modules. If both modules don't have much in common in term of look and feel and they doesn't have to share same state, this should be a solution you could consider. 
With this solution, you also should route from one application to another using `href` rather than `routerLink/router.navigate()`.